# On RNIap.requestSubscription(sku) returns undefind, on purchase successful in iOS React-Native

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

on click request for subscription and
Confirm on device then Dialog will show saying: "You're all set. Your purchase was successful. [Environment: Xcode]"

purchaseUpdatedListener and requestSubcription callback doesn't return any value or transaction receipt. It's just undefined.

```
 RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener((purchase) => {
  console.log(purchase); // undefined
})
```